# How to get values from neon file in Nette?

Tags: php, nette

I have small application based on Nette framework.

I've created `constants.neon` file and add it to container. There will be some data which should be available from presenters, models, forms etc.

How can I access to values in `constants.neon`?

I know that there is a method `(new \Nette\Neon\Neon())->decode([NEON_FILE_PATH])` but I don't think that this is the `right way`. I suspect that after using `addConfig(...)` in `bootstrap.php` all data from those config files should be available all over the system.

```
<?php
// bootstrap.php
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$configurator = new Nette\Configurator;

$configurator->setDebugMode(true); // enable for your remote IP
$configurator->enableDebugger(__DIR__ . '/../log');

$configurator->setTempDirectory(__DIR__ . '/../temp');

$configurator->createRobotLoader()
    ->addDirectory(__DIR__)
    ->addDirectory(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel')
    ->register();

$configurator->addConfig(__DIR__ . '/config/config.neon');
$configurator->addConfig(__DIR__ . '/config/config.local.neon');
$configurator->addConfig(__DIR__ . '/config/constants.neon');

$container = $configurator->createContainer();

return $container;
```

My `constants.neon` file:

```
constants:
  DP_OPT = 'DP'
  PP_OPT = 'PP'
  DV_OPT = 'DV'
  ZM_OPT = 'ZM'
  TP_OPT = 'TP'
```

Thanks

**UPDATE #1**

Figured out that I've used wrong format of `.neon` file.

```
constants:
  DP_OPT: DP
  PP_OPT: PP
  DV_OPT: DV
  ZM_OPT: ZM
  TP_OPT: TP
```

Answer (score 9):

To complete Jan's answer, here's how you pass your config parameters to a model.

Make your model class expect it as a constructor parameter:

```
namespace App\XXX;
class MyModel
{
  /** @var array */
  private $constants;

  public function __construct(array $constants)
  {
    $this->constants = $constants;
  }
```

Then register your model as a service in config (Neon):

```
services:
    - App\XXX\MyModel(%constants%)
```

When you inject that model into your presenter:

```
class DefaultPresenter extends BasePresenter
{
  /** @var App\XXX\MyModel @inject */
  public $myModel;
```

it will automatically receive your 'constants' when instantialized.

Answer (score 7):

If you store the constants inside `parameters` array in the neon file, you will be able to access it from presenter’s [*context*](https://api.nette.org/2.4/Nette.Application.UI.Presenter.html#m$context) like this:

```
// $this is instance of Nette\Application\UI\Presenter
$this->context->parameters['constants']
```

Neon file:

```
parameters:
    constants:
        DP_OPT: DP
        PP_OPT: PP
        DV_OPT: DV
        ZM_OPT: ZM
        TP_OPT: TP
```

Please note that this might not be recommended approach. For more information see how to use [presenter as a service](https://doc.nette.org/en/2.4/di-usage#toc-presenter-as-a-service).

Comment: Thanks this works fine for me! BTW is it possible to get the same result but using `custom.neon` file which is added to container by `addConfig()`?

Comment: This should work with any file, as long as you add it to container.